# Trying to display both the original text and the modified text with the changes highlighted in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm comparing two texts or emails in this case with each other. I altered one of the texts and I did a simple gui that should display both the edited text and the original with the lines that were altered highlighted red but no matter what i do it always displays the edited text in both of the widgets and it has the top part highlighted no matter what.

I tried to only include the methods where the bug could be but since I've sat with this for hours I'm not so sure anymore.

email_viewer.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext


class EmailViewer(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, subject, original_body, cleaned_body, removed_indices):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title(subject)
        self.geometry("800x600")

        # Create two text widgets for original and cleaned bodies
        self.original_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(
            self, height=15, width=100, wrap=tk.WORD
        )
        self.original_text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.cleaned_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(
            self, height=15, width=100, wrap=tk.WORD
        )
        self.cleaned_text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        # Insert the original and cleaned bodies into the text widgets
        self.original_text.insert(tk.END, original_body)
        self.cleaned_text.insert(tk.END, cleaned_body)

        # Apply the "removed" tag configuration
        self.original_text.tag_config("removed", background="red")

        # Highlight the removed lines in the original text
        for start, end in removed_indices:
            self.original_text.tag_add("removed", f"{start}.0", f"{end}.end")

        # Highlight the removed lines in the cleaned text
        cleaned_removed_indices = [
            (start, end - (start + 1)) for start, end in removed_indices
        ]
        for start, end in cleaned_removed_indices:
            self.cleaned_text.tag_add("removed", f"{start}.0", f"{end}.end")
```

the class which alters the email and then saves it.

```
class EmailProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.removed_text_indices = {}
        self.content_text = {}
        self.removed_text_indices = {}

    def remove_specific_lines(self, email_body, subject):
        lines_to_remove = ["Från:", "Skickat:", "Till:", "Ämne:"]
        cleaned_body = []
        removed_indices = []
        lines = email_body.splitlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if any(line.lstrip().startswith(phrase) for phrase in lines_to_remove):
                removed_indices.append(
                    (i + 1, i + 2)
                )  # Assuming line numbers start from 1
                continue
            cleaned_body.append(line)
        return "\n".join(cleaned_body), removed_indices

    def save_email_to_file(self, email, output_dir, progress_text, subject_listbox):
        try:
            sanitized_subject = re.sub(r"[^\w\s.-]", "", email.Subject)
            filename = f"{sanitized_subject[:100]}.txt"  # Truncate to 100 characters to avoid very long filenames
            file_path = output_dir / filename
            email_body = email.Body
            original_body, removed_indices = self.remove_specific_lines(
                email_body, email.Subject
            )

            self.removed_text_indices[email.Subject] = removed_indices
            with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.write(f"Subject: {email.Subject}\n\n")
                file.write(f"Body:\n{original_body}")

            progress_text.insert(
                tk.END, f"Saved email '{email.Subject}' from {email.Parent.Name}\n"
            )
            progress_text.yview(tk.END)

            subject_listbox.insert(tk.END, email.Subject)
            self.content_text[email.Subject] = original_body

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error saving email '{email.Subject}' from {email.Parent.Name}: {e}")
            progress_text.insert(
                tk.END,
                f"Error saving email '{email.Subject}' from {email.Parent.Name}: {e}\n",
            )
            progress_text.yview(tk.END)

    def get_email_content(self, subject):
        return self.content_text.get(subject, ""), self.removed_text_indices.get(
            subject, []
        )

    def get_cleaned_email(self, subject):
        return self.content_text.get(subject, "")

    def retrieve_emails(self, output_dir, progress_text, subject_listbox):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(
            6
        )  # 6 is the folder number for Inbox in Outlook

        folder_names = [
            "22. Assignments from Combitech",
            "23. Assignments from Broccoli",
            "24. Assignments from Levigo",
        ]

        email_count = 0

        for name in folder_names:
            try:
                folder = inbox.Folders[name]
                for email in folder.Items:
                    email_count += 1
                    self.save_email_to_file(
                        email, output_dir, progress_text, subject_listbox
                    )
            except Exception as e:
                progress_text.insert(tk.END, f"Error accessing folder {name}: {e}\n")
                progress_text.yview(tk.END)

    def run_script(self, output_folder, progress_text, subject_listbox):
        output_dir = Path(output_folder)
        output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        progress_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        subject_listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.content_text.clear()
        self.removed_text_indices.clear()
        self.retrieve_emails(output_dir, progress_text, subject_listbox)
```

email_scaper.py main class

```
class EmailScraperApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Email Retrieval GUI")

        self.email_processor = EmailProcessor()

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="10")
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))

        output_folder_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Output Folder:")
        output_folder_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

        self.output_folder_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=50)
        self.output_folder_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

        choose_folder_button = ttk.Button(
            frame, text="Choose Folder", command=self.choose_folder
        )
        choose_folder_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

        progress_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Progress:")
        progress_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

        self.progress_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame, height=5, width=60)
        self.progress_text.grid(
            row=2,
            column=0,
            columnspan=3,
            padx=5,
            pady=5,
            sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S),
        )

        subject_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Email Subjects:")
        subject_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

        self.subject_listbox = Listbox(frame, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, height=10, width=60)
        self.subject_listbox.grid(
            row=4,
            column=0,
            columnspan=3,
            padx=5,
            pady=5,
            sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S),
        )

        self.subject_listbox.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_subject_select)

        run_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Run Script", command=self.run_script)
        run_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)

    def choose_folder(self):
        folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.output_folder_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.output_folder_entry.insert(0, folder)

    def on_subject_select(self, event):
        selected_index = self.subject_listbox.curselection()[0]
        subject = self.subject_listbox.get(selected_index)
        original_body, removed_indices = self.email_processor.get_email_content(subject)
        cleaned_body = self.email_processor.get_cleaned_email(subject)
        EmailViewer(self.root, subject, original_body, cleaned_body, removed_indices)

    def run_script(self):
        try:
            output_folder = self.output_folder_entry.get()
            self.email_processor.run_script(
                output_folder, self.progress_text, self.subject_listbox
            )
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Email retrieval completed.")
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred: {ex}")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = EmailScraperApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the intermediate values along the way? Right now you've got finding and scraping emails, changing them, comparing changes, and displaying them in tkinter; somewhere along the line, something wrong is being passed to something. Try stepping through it with a debugger, or sprinkling in liberal `print` calls checking what each step gets and produces.